# NodeJS packing and unpacking as buffer slower than JSON

Tags: node.js, json, serialization, binary, deserialization

I wrote this simple test to compare the speeds of serializing an array of objects as binary and JSON.

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

let units = [];
let id = 0;
let CHUNK_SIZE = 23;

for (let i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {

  let r = Math.random();

  let u = {};
  u.id = id;
  u.rotation = Math.PI * 2 * Math.random();
  u.type = 0;
  u.x = i;
  u.y = i;
  u.size = r * 20 + 12;
  u.health = 1;
  u.int = 1;

  units.push(u);
}

[
  [
    "JSON",
    (units) => JSON.stringify(units.map(unit => [
      unit.id,
      unit.type,
      unit.x.toFixed(0),
      unit.y.toFixed(0),
      unit.rotation.toFixed(4),
      unit.health.toFixed(2),
      unit.size.toFixed(0),
      parseInt(unit.int)
    ])),
    (units) => JSON.parse(units)
  ],
  [
    "Binary",
    (units) => {
      return Buffer.concat(units.map(unit => {
        let buf = new Buffer(CHUNK_SIZE);

        buf.writeUInt32BE(unit.id);
        buf.writeUInt8(unit.type, 4);
        buf.writeInt32BE(unit.x, 5);
        buf.writeInt32BE(unit.y, 9);
        buf.writeFloatBE(unit.rotation, 13);
        buf.writeFloatBE(unit.health, 17);
        buf.writeUInt8(unit.size, 21);
        buf.writeUInt8(unit.attacking ? 1 : 0, 22);

        return buf;
      }));
    },
    (units) => {
      let u = units.buffer;
      let result = [];

      for (let offset = 0; offset < u.byteLength; offset += CHUNK_SIZE) {
        let view = new DataView(u, offset, CHUNK_SIZE);

        result.push([
          view.getUint32(0), 
          view.getUint8(4), 
          view.getInt32(5), 
          view.getInt32(9), 
          view.getFloat32(13), 
          view.getFloat32(17), 
          view.getUint8(21), 
          view.getUint8(22)
        ]);
      }

      return result;
    }
  ]
].forEach(([name, compress, decompress]) => {
  console.log("Test: " + name);

  let t0 = performance.now();

  let compressed = compress(units);

  let t1 = performance.now();

  let decompressed = decompress(compressed);

  let t2 = performance.now();

  console.log(`Result: ${decompressed.length}`);
  console.log(`Compression took: ${t1 - t0}ms`);
  console.log(`Compressed length: ${compressed.byteLength || compressed.length}`);
  console.log(`Decompression took: ${t2 - t1}ms`);
  console.log(`Total time: ${t2 - t0}ms`);
  console.log("");
})
```

Drop that into NodeJS and look at the results, here are mine

```
Test: JSON
Result: 50000
Compression took: 411.7958119995892ms
Compressed length: 2227781
Decompression took: 134.79507100209594ms
Total time: 546.5908830016851ms

Test: Binary
Result: 50000
Compression took: 612.1825229972601ms
Compressed length: 1150000
Decompression took: 191.14320900291204ms
Total time: 803.3257320001721ms
```

I'm quite surprised to find that JSON is faster since it is doing considerably more work than the binary counterpart.

Why is that and how can it be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I don't look like a weirdo answering, like a third consecutive, question I asked myself, but hopefully I'm providing content that could be useful for someone.

It appears as if I have been taking way too much advantage of convenience functions. Combine that with not knowing exactly what is happening "under the hood" and you get the results from the question.

Constructing a new buffer for each entry and then concatenating them seems like a costly thing to do. Instead create a single buffer and add to that:

```
(units) => {
  let buf = new Buffer(units.length * CHUNK_SIZE);

  units.forEach((unit, i) => {
    let offset = i * CHUNK_SIZE;

    buf.writeUInt32BE(unit.id, offset);
    buf.writeUInt8(unit.type, offset + 4);
    buf.writeInt32BE(unit.x, offset + 5);
    buf.writeInt32BE(unit.y, offset + 9);
    buf.writeFloatBE(unit.rotation, offset + 13);
    buf.writeFloatBE(unit.health, offset + 17);
    buf.writeUInt8(unit.size, offset + 21);
    buf.writeUInt8(unit.attacking ? 1 : 0, offset + 22);
  });

  return buf;
},
```

Same goes on the unserializing part, instead of constructing a new DataView, which can mislead you to believe it would be more effective as it's constructor takes an offset and length, construct one and read off of it:

```
(units) => {
  let u = units.buffer;
  let result = [];
  let view = new DataView(u);

  for (let offset = 0; offset < u.byteLength; offset += CHUNK_SIZE) {

    result.push([
      view.getUint32(offset + 0), 
      view.getUint8(offset + 4), 
      view.getInt32(offset + 5), 
      view.getInt32(offset + 9), 
      view.getFloat32(offset + 13), 
      view.getFloat32(offset + 17), 
      view.getUint8(offset + 21), 
      view.getUint8(offset + 22)
    ]);
  }

  return result;
}
```

And now we've got more acceptable results:

```
Test: JSON
Result: 50000
Compression took: 284.3018040023744ms
Compressed length: 2934399
Decompression took: 197.91818399727345ms
Total time: 522.21998799964786ms

Test: Binary
Result: 50000
Compression took: 175.56888100132346ms
Compressed length: 1150000
Decompression took: 79.27483800053596ms
Total time: 254.84371900185943ms
```

JSON length has increased because I removed the `.toFixed` calls from the compress function.

I'm interested if there are further improvements that can be done, as I'm sure there are plenty of people who are more competent than me out there.